# How do I get the userid of second mention in a command

Tags: node.js, discord.js

So I'm trying to make a command where someone can do -kill @firstUser @secondUser. This will increase the first user's kills by 1 and add a role to the second user mentioned. I can access the the first user mentioned by doing const firstUser = message.mentions.users.first(); but I'm not sure how to do the same for the second user.

I've tried accessing the message.mentions.users collection and converting it to an array (and trying to access that) but I can't get it to work.

```
const firstUser = message.mentions.users.get(0); 
const secondUser = message.mentions.users.get(1);
```

How do I get the user class from a message with multiple mentions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: I Tested this some time ago.]

And what I found was, it returns an object, not a mention, and as you can't send an object, it will return as an empty message error.
So to send a mention, you send:

```
// Getting the first and second users
const allMentioned = message.mentions.users.array()
// First User `[0]`
const firstUser = allMentioned[0];
// Second User `[1]`
const secondUser = allMentioned[1];
// And so on and so forth...

// Add `<@` to the begginning of the id and `>` to the end of it to make a mention.
const mentionSecondUser = "<@" + secondUser.id + ">";
// Sending a message using the fetched property
message.channel.send(`Hey ${mentionSecondUser}, or whatever.`);
```

Alternatively, you can try using the other fetched properties using the following format, received from getting the property, say `secondUser`:

```
User {
  id: '<secondUser's id>',
  username: '<secondUser's username>',
  bot: <true if secondUser a bot>,
  discriminator: '<secondUser's discriminator>',
  avatar: '<secondUser's avatarId>',
  lastMessageID: <secondUser's lastMessageId>,
  lastMessageChannelID: <secondUser's lastMessageChannelId>,
  flags: UserFlags { bitfield: 0 }
}
```

An example of this is in the picture showed above.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```js
message.mentions.users.array()[1]
```

To get the second user in a message. Appropriately, use `[2]` for the third, `[3]` for the fourth, and so on.

Comment: When I try that:
const firstUser = message.mentions.users.array()[0];
message.channel.send(firstUser);

I get the error "UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message"

Comment: If you'd like to send it in a message, you should do `firstUser.username`, `firstUser.tag`, or `'<@' + firstUser.id + '>'` (which will mention them)